# Extract text between two strings repeating multiple times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I have a sample text data as following:

> 1;abc;111;10-nov-2017 2;**abc**;222;**11-nov-2017**
>   3;abc;333;12-nov-2017

Given 2 inputs **abc** and **11-nov1017** I want to extract string between both i.e. **222**

How can get the result using `regex`? Is there any other way to achieve the same?

The actual data is like:

> 113434;Axis Gold ETF;2651.2868;2651.2868;2651.2868;20-Nov-2017
>   113434;Axis Gold ETF;2627.6778;2627.6778;2627.6778;21-Nov-2017
>   113434;Axis Gold ETF;2624.1880;2624.1880;2624.1880;22-Nov-2017

Any help, highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: and what have you tried

Comment: I tried data[/#{'abc;'}(.*?)#{';11-nov1017'}/m, 1] but its returning ;111;10-nov-2017 2;abc;222; i.e. data between first abc and 11-nov1017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two ways to extract the desired substring, if it is present. We are given the following.

```
str = "1;abc;111;10-nov-2017 2;abc;222;11-nov-2017 3;abc;333;12-nov-2017"
before_str = "abc;"
date_str   = ";11-nov-2017"
```

I assume that the value of `date_str` appears at most once in `str`.

**#1 Use a regular expression**

```
r = /
    .*            # match any number of characters greedily
    #{before_str} # match the content of the variable 'before_str'
    (.*)          # match any number characters greedily, in capture group 1
    #{date_str}   # match the content of the variable 'date_str'
    /x            # free-spacing regex definition mode
  #=> /.*abc;(.*);11-nov-2017/x

str[r,1]
  #=> "222"
```

The key here is `.*` at the beginning of the regular expression. Being a greedy match it causes the next match to be the last instance of `"abc;"` (the value of `before_str`) that precedes `";11-nov-2017"` (the value of `date_str`).

**#2 Determine indices for the beginning and end of the desired subtring**

```
idx_date = str.index(date_str)
  #=> str.index(";11-nov-2017") => 31
idx_before = str.rindex(before_str, idx_date-before_str.size)
  #=> str.rindex("abc;", 27) => 24
str[idx_before + before_str.size..idx_date-1]
  #=> str[24+4..31-1] => str[28..30] => "222"
```

If either `idx_date` or `idx_before` were `nil`, `nil` would be returned and the last expression would not be evaluated.

See [String#rindex](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-rindex), especially the function of the optional second argument.

(One could write `str[idx_before + date_str.before...idx_date]`, but I find the use of three dots in ranges to be a potential source of error, so I always use two dots.)

Comment: Perfect! Makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

you can have a look at the result of:
/abc(.*?)10-nov-2017/g.exec("1;abc;111;10-nov-2017 2;abc;222;11-nov-2017 3;abc;333;12-nov-2017")[1]